# cannot find embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

i am trying to find product reviews , based on their  product id from  products collection,

Below is the code for finding that reviews that has id that matches product id , it is a nested object in reviewInfo object

```
const reviewid  = req.params.product_id
reviewSchema.find({reviewInfo:{reviewId:reviewid}}).then((value,err) => {console.log(value)})
```

i also have provided an image of my review schema

all i am getting is empty array .[image shows the reviewproduct schema structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNVd6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this query it just want to find an object exactly like this :

```
{reviewId:reviewid}
```

your query should be like this :

```
const reviewid  = req.params.product_id reviewSchema.find({'reviewInfo.reviewId':reviewid}}).then((value,err)
=> {console.log(value)})
```

Comment: i followed  method  provided by monogdb docs    for matching embeded docs,,    i used the same method            like     db.inventory.find( { size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } } ) . why was this not working?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are passing the wrong filter.

You should use a filter,

```
{"reviewInfo.reviewId":reviewId}
```

so your code will be like,

```
const reviewid  = req.params.product_id
reviewSchema.find({"reviewInfo.reviewId":reviewId}).then((value,err) => {console.log(value)})
```